# UI Interface Crashes and Hanging Issues in MFC Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, automation, mfc, desktop-application

I encountered an error in the MFC application during runtime. When the application is idle, it crashes, causing the UI to disappear, and I can't click anything in the application. I have to go to the task manager and end the process.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BBES.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BBES.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPP54.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPP54.png)

I want to fix the application and ensure it runs smoothly without any crash or hanging issues. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Refactor your code to have all business logic seperated from UI and add unit tests. Make sure NO C++ exceptions make it into the windows mainloop etc. etc.  Do NOT make blocking calls on the windows mainloop, but move all "long duration" activities to background threads. And maybe just maybe it is time to stop using MFC for UI development.

Comment: a) attach debugger to hung process, or if it is not possible, b) run with debugger , or  c) used procdump or similar tool tp get an image to inspect ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump )

Comment: The screenshots suggest an issue with GDI/User objects (either a leak or use-after-free). An easy way to find out whether this is a leak is using Task Manager: Switch to the *Details* view, right-click the header, and select *GDI objects* and *User objects*. If either of those numbers keep growing you probably have a resource leak. If, on the other hand, the application fails when it goes idle it could be a use-after-free bug instead. MFC implements a non-deterministic garbage collector for GDI objects that runs during idle processing.